# Gauge group as a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, principal-bundles

Let $\pi\colon P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle, where $G$ is a Lie group, the gauge group $\mathscr{G}(P)$ is the group of $G$-automorphism of $P$, that is $G$-equivariant diffeomorphism $\Phi:P\to P$ such that $\pi=\pi\circ\Phi$.

Now I have three questions:

1. I need to know why $\mathscr{G}(P)$ is a Lie group? what is it's smooth structure?
2. Is $\mathscr{G}(P)$ a compact Lie group?
3. I know there is a one to one correspondence between $\mathscr{G}(P)$ and $C^{\infty}(M,Ad P)$, how to show its Lie algebra is $C^{\infty}(M,ad P)$, where $Ad P$ is the associated vector bundle given by conjugate action and $ad P$ is the associated vector bundle given by adjoint action.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I believe $\mathscr{G}(P)$ is an infinite-dimensional Lie group. I am not sure what topology is put on the charts, but infinite dimensional Lie groups are in general not compact. Furthermore, I believe some people sometimes call $G$ the "gauge group", besides the full $\mathscr{G}(P)$.

Comment: Also, I am confused by the $C^\infty(M,\mathrm{Ad}P)$ notation. Say I have some $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathrm{Ad}P)$, shouldn't you also require that $\pi_{\mathrm{Ad}P}(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in M$, i.e. that $f$ is a _section_. Sometimes, the notation $\Gamma^\infty(M,\mathrm{Ad}P)$ is used for sections.

Comment: @student91 $C^\infty (M,E)$ is commonly used notation for the space of smooth sections of the bundle $E$ over $M$.